# Update Field based Transaction where type = bill payment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We want to save the last bill payment on the vendor record.
I've created a field on the vendor.
I created a script that need to executed when transaction (bill payment) is updated.

When I try to deploy the script and attach it to a record, I'm not finding transaction

What am I missing ?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: What you're missing is the script that you were going to include with the question so that we can help you with it.  Also, it seems that the same information is available in the Transactions sublist under the Financial tab - what are you trying to achieve that's not available there?

Answer (score 0):

In Netsuite, most forms you see have a 'type'.  Transaction is a general category, too general to actually deploy to.  If you go to a Bill Payment record, and open up your debugger, and type in `nlapiGetRecordType()`, you'll get `vendorbill`.  You should be able to deploy to the 'Vendor Bill' record and I think that will work (you'll have to check though).